# ColdFusion Objects Overwriting Other Objects When Web Services Called

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, cfml

Related to [ColdFusion 2021 Returns "object is not an instance of declaring class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817268/coldfusion-2021-returns-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class):

We installed ColdFusion2021 on a different server, and in a different section of code, one web service object seems to be overwriting other web service objects (or at least, everything is getting converted to instances of that object).

```
oWsdlArgs = structNew();
oWsdlArgs.refreshwsdl="yes"
objSoapHeader = XmlParse("<wsse:Security mustUnderstand=""true"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd""><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>#Application.Settings.ws_user#</wsse:Username><wsse:Password>#Application.Settings.ws_password#</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>");
            
Application.ValidationWebService = CreateObject("webservice", Application.Settings.ws_url & "Validation/WSValidation.asmx?WSDL", oWsdlArgs);
addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.ValidationWebService,"","",objSoapHeader,true);

Application.ClientAccessWS = CreateObject("webservice", Application.Settings.ws_url & "Admin/ClientAccess/WSClientAccess.asmx?WSDL", oWsdlArgs);
addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.ClientAccessWS,"","",objSoapHeader,true);

Application.AdminWS = CreateObject("webservice", Application.Settings.ws_url & "Admin/AdminSite/WSAdminSite.asmx?WSDL", oWsdlArgs);
addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.AdminWS,"","",objSoapHeader,true);

Application.EmailService = CreateObject("webservice", Application.Settings.ws_url & "Requests/EmailService.asmx?WSDL", oWsdlArgs);
addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.EmailService, "", "", objSoapHeader, true);

Application.UserWebService = CreateObject("webservice", Application.Settings.ws_url & "Requests/UserService.asmx?WSDL", oWsdlArgs);
addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.UserWebService,"","",objSoapHeader,true);

// Get the .Net resources
Application.NetResources = Application.UserWebService.GetNetResources(Application.LanguageHeader); 

Application.WhiteLabelService = CreateObject("webservice", Application.Settings.ws_url & "Requests/WhiteLabelService.asmx?WSDL", oWsdlArgs);
addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.WhiteLabelService,"","",objSoapHeader,true);

// Initialize resource manager
createObject("component", "#Application.GlobalComponentPath#ResourceManager").init(Application.Settings.defaultBaseCategory);
```

It appears as though every one of the created objects is being set to an instance of WhiteLabelServiceStub.  For example, here is a dump of what should be an AdminWS, but is actually being set to a WhiteLabelServiceStub:

```
 object of org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceStub
Class Name  org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceStub
Methods 
Method  Return Type
getAllConfigs(org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)  java.lang.String
getConfigId(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)  int
getDisclaimer(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)  java.lang.String
getPopup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)   java.lang.String
getProgress(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)  java.lang.String
getResourceManagerByCategory(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE) org.tempuri.CfResourceManager
getText(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)  java.lang.String
keepAlive(org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)
reloadKeys(java.lang.String)    void
reportException(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE)    java.lang.String
startgetAllConfigs(org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)   void
startgetConfigId(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)   void
startgetDisclaimer(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)   void
startgetPopup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)    void
startgetProgress(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)   void
startgetResourceManagerByCategory(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)  void
startgetText(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)   void
startkeepAlive(org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler)   void
startreloadKeys(java.lang.String, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler) void
startreportException(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.tempuri.LanguageHeaderE, org.tempuri.WhiteLabelServiceCallbackHandler) void
Parent Class
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Would need to see your code for those two root objects. Feels like there are some incorrectly scoped variables in there somewhere. Like something needs to be `var` scoped to a function instead of put into the `variables` or `this` scope.

Comment: Yep, I found the same confusion about the webservice being called while migrating to CF2021 by dumping the webservice like you did.  So far the answer seems to be to instantiate the webservice on every request instead of using a cached version (we had a caching system similar to yours but not on the application scope.  I haven't bothered to report to adobe yet.