# Webservice breaks on Coldfusion 2021 (java 11)

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

We consume webservices from a vender using CF.  The webservices have always worked fine with cf2016 and java 8.  Now we are migrating from CF2016 to CF2021 (java 11) and all of the venders webservices work fine except 1 breaks.  If I understand correctly a webservice is client agnostic so the issue has to be with cf2021 (java 11)?  Or am I wrong? below is the error I get when trying to invoke the 1 bad method.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **object is not an instance of declaring class** at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.Axis1ServiceProxy.getResult(Axis1ServiceProxy.java:103) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.ServiceProxy.invokeImpl(ServiceProxy.java:480) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:421) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:4239) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:4202) at
> cfSakaiDataService2ecfc1435138273$funcGETGRADEBOOKASSIGNMENTSANDSCORES.runFunction(D:\inetpub\wwwroot\SakaiToolsCommonLS\SakaiDataService.cfc:568)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Reflection - Object is not an instance of declaring class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336057/java-reflection-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class)

Comment: I don't see this question as a duplicate of the one specified in the vote to close.

Comment: It's hard to determine the problem without more info. Please post the code you are using and indicate which line is throwing the error.  Is that the complete trace message  or does it mention other classes? If it's a public web service, please post the URL.

Comment: Part of the issue seems to be CF2021 screwing up which web service is actually being called when using a cached webservice for example on application scope.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924748/coldfusion-objects-overwriting-other-objects-when-web-services-called

Comment: The answer is NOT to cache webservices bc CF gets mixed up... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924748/coldfusion-objects-overwriting-other-objects-when-web-services-called